# why is my variable elecfirebase always equal to [ ]?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have i do a request, after this my variable (elecfirebase) is always [ ]

```
function a(){
let elecfirebase=[]
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/fournisseurs")
        .child(0)
        .child("data")
        .on("value", data => {
          elecfirebase=data.val();    
      });
console.log("elecfirebase ",elecfirebase)
}
```

Comment: What is `data.val()` returning? Anything?

Comment: can you move `console.log("elecfirebase ",elecfirebase)` inside `.on("value", data => {
          elecfirebase=data.val();    
          console.log("elecfirebase ",elecfirebase)
      });`

Comment: it return an array from firebase !

Comment: when i move `console.log("elecfirebase ",elecfirebase) });` inside, i have the good output

Comment: Yeah but you have `console.log` outside and firebase function is async it will fire after getting data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`console.log("elecfirebase ",elecfirebase)` 
Above console.log will always give you [] because firebase function is async function

You can call a function after getting the data like as follows

```js
function a(){
    let elecfirebase=[]
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/fournisseurs")
        .child(0)
        .child("data")
        .on("value", data => {
          elecfirebase=data.val(); 
          onData(elecfirebase);
      });

}
function onData(elecfirebase){
     console.log(elecfirebase)
}
```

If you want to use this value somewhere else too then use callback or promise. Here is the example of callback

```js
function foo(){
...
...
//calling function with callback
a(function(elecfirebase){

})
...
...
}

function a(callback){
    let elecfirebase=[]
    firebase
        .database()
        .ref("/fournisseurs")
        .child(0)
        .child("data")
        .on("value", data => {
          elecfirebase=data.val(); 
          callback(elecfirebase);
      });

}
```

Hope it will be helpful

Comment: Thx for this answers!

Comment: But here , i want to return elecfirebase from a();  i put  console.log() to verify the output

Comment: Then you need to use callback because this is async method

Comment: I have added example of the callback

Comment: is it possible to do `let value= a(function(elecfirebase){ return elecfirebase})` ?

Comment: So value will get the array that a(...) will return